# bash script to run through each folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to run a bash script through every folder but how can i do that best?

this the script that needs to run in every folder
Also i need to keep track of the folder where the files are with $Title

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f output2.txt
rm -f output3.txt
ls -td $PWD/test/*.pdf |head -5 >> output2.txt
ls -t test/ | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//' | head -5 >> output3.txt
output2=output2.txt
output3=output3.txt


download_one=$(awk 'FNR==1' $output2)
download_two=$(awk 'FNR==2' $output2)
download_three=$(awk 'FNR==3' $output2)
download_four=$(awk 'FNR==4' $output2)
download_five=$(awk 'FNR==5' $output2)

download_one_title=$(awk 'FNR==1' $output3)
download_two_title=$(awk 'FNR==2' $output3)
download_three_title=$(awk 'FNR==3' $output3)
download_four_title=$(awk 'FNR==4' $output3)
download_five_title=$(awk 'FNR==5' $output3)

rm -f output2.txt
rm -f output3.txt

Title=
Title2=$Title

echo $Title,$Title2,$download_one_title,$download_one,$download_two_title,$download_two,$download_three_title,$download_three,$download_four_title,$download_four,$download_five_title,$download_five >> test.csv
```

second 
errors

```
    /home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test1/script: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test1/script: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test1/script: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /home/intranet/test/test1/test/*/*.pdf: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access test/: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test2/script: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test2/script: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test2/script: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /home/intranet/test/test2/test/*/*.pdf: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access test/: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test3/script: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test3/script: No such file or directory
/home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test3/script: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /home/intranet/test/test3/test/*/*.pdf: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access test/: No such file or directory
```

Second code

```
    #!/bin/bash

curdir=$(pwd)
for folder in /home/intranet/test/*; do
    [ -d $folder ] && cd "$folder" && $curdir/script
done
cd $curdir

rm -f output2.txt
rm -f output3.txt
ls -td $PWD/test/*/*.pdf |head -5 >> output2.txt
ls -t test/ | sed -e 's/\.[^.]*$//' | head -5 >> output3.txt
output2=output2.txt
output3=output3.txt


download_one=$(awk 'FNR==1' $output2)
download_two=$(awk 'FNR==2' $output2)
download_three=$(awk 'FNR==3' $output2)
download_four=$(awk 'FNR==4' $output2)
download_five=$(awk 'FNR==5' $output2)

download_one_title=$(awk 'FNR==1' $output3)
download_two_title=$(awk 'FNR==2' $output3)
download_three_title=$(awk 'FNR==3' $output3)
download_four_title=$(awk 'FNR==4' $output3)
download_five_title=$(awk 'FNR==5' $output3)

rm -f output2.txt
rm -f output3.txt

Title=lol
Title2=$Title

echo $Title,$Title2,$download_one_title,$download_one,$download_two_title,$download_two,$download_three_title,$download_three,$download_four_title,$download_four,$download_five_title,$download_five >> test.csv
```

Comment: The `./script` errors from your second script are because you have changed working directory and presumably your script is in your original directory. You need to use `$curdir/script` there instead.

Comment: I tried but get a lot of errors: /home/intranet/script: line 5: /home/intranet/test/test3/script: No such file or directory

Comment: Where are you running the script from in the first place? You did use `$curdir` like in the edited post and not `$PWD` in that line in the for loop, right?

Comment: @EtanReisner in the home directory are test/ and my script

Comment: If you ran the script from your home directory and used `$curdir` in the for loop (and set it with `$(pwd)` like in the second script above I don't see how that error could happen.

Comment: @EtanReisner i updated the code and the errors above. just one question between: i want to short every folder on date and the latest 5 file from every folder must be in a csv file.

Comment: Your script can't call itself on each directory if the script itself has that loop in it. You **either** loop over each directory and call a script that only operates on one directory **or** you write a script that loops over each directory and does the work for each looped over directory, not both.

Answer (score 2):

```
find /path/to/Files -type d -exec myscript.sh {} \;
```

find normaly do your job and you can specify lot more option to filter folder like time or access, ...

Comment: do i have to put that in separate script or in the same script. I'm very novice with bash

Comment: @TheHell34 Run it from command line. `myscript.sh` should be the name of the file which contains your own script.

Comment: @Qeole i did get a error script: open failed: /home/intranet/test/test1: Is a directory
Terminated

Comment: @Qeole With this your script needs to be written to expect to get the directory to operate on as its first (and only) argument. That error sounds like that isn't the case. Also with this `$PWD` in the script will not work correctly.

Comment: Indeed. @TheHell34: try adding `cd $1` at the very beginning of your script (below shebang), and try again.

Comment: @TheHell34 maybe a `cd "$1"` is better due to possible space in folder/path name